# Run a tensorflow session in cherrypy

Tags: python, tensorflow, cherrypy

I have a tensorflow session code

```
sess = tf.Session()
pool3 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('incept/pool_3:0')
pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{png_data: image_data})
```

where `image_data` is a binary data of an image. This code runs perfectly when run on my terminal. But for some reason goes into a timeout when running through a cherrypy server.

Debugging via adding log statements after each line, tells me

`pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{png_data: image_data})`

this line never completes its execution. How do I have tensorflow run in cherrypy server?

Comment: Could it be that you are (accidentally?) sharing the session object across multiple threads? Or is the `image_data`  being generated using a Queue?

Comment: Have you tried starting queue runners before evaluating something? It might be that this graph needs queue runners for some reason.

Comment: It's recommended to schedule long-running tasks using smth like RQ or Celery. You may otherwise try enlarging [`response.timeout`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#response-timeouts) value

Comment: @musically_ut maybe, I am not sure. Session is being initialised as a global variable as soon as I start cherrypy session and then used when ajax function is called.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I haven't tried it. But I will have a look.

Comment: @webKnjaZ I will try it again. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShashankGandham That may be an issue. I've never needed to do it, but perhaps creating a new session per AJAX call would address the issue. However, it may not be the (computationally?) optimal solution. Another option worth considering maybe [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/).

Comment: @musically_ut , yes it did solve the problem. But again like you said, it slows down the process. I will have a look Tensorflow serving